# BASH: Escribir un número aleatorio hasta que el usuario escriba "s" o "S"

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Tengo que hacer un script en el cual mediante un bucle, se vayan imprimiendo por pantalla números aleatorios pero en el momento en que yo escriba "s" o "S" y le de al "Intro", me pare el bucle y se me salga del programa.

De momento he hecho esto:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "A continuació s'escriuràn numeros aleatoris."
echo "Si en qualsevol moment vols parar, pressiona la tecla 's' o 'S'."
    read $exit_key

while  [ "$exit_key" != 's' ] || [ "$exit_key" != 'S' ]
    do
        random_num=$RANDOM
        echo "$random_num"
        ##((cont++))
    done
```

El resultado en el terminal es el siguiente:

```
alumne@PC-VirtualBox:~/Escriptori$ sudo ./2.sh
A continuació s'escriuràn numeros aleatoris.
Si en qualsevol moment vols parar, pressiona la tecla 'S'.

23816
23054
22981
1119
...
```

Al introducir cualquier valor, me hace el bucle infinito.
Incluso antes de entrar, si escribo 's' o 'S' me entra al bucle igual.
Y también, si cuando el bucle está ejecutándose, escribo 's' o 'S', no me hace nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para empezar, si quieres definir una variable con contenido que ingrese el usuario, utiliza esto.

```
read exit_key
```

Es decir, elimina el signo de pesos (o dólar o como le llames) `$` al definir. Sólo lo usaras cuando hagas uso de la variable, no al definirla.

Después, otro problema de tu script es la lógica, es decir, en la línea donde preguntas

```
while  [ "$exit_key" != 's' ] || [ "$exit_key" != 'S' ]
```

osea, si el usuario escribe algo diferente de "s" o de "S" te los avienta en la cara, entonces, cuando lo ejecutas e introduces, digamos, la letra "s" resulta que eso pasa la primera condición, es decir resulta falso, lo cual es bueno, pero resulta que "s" y "S" son diferentes, lo cual da verdadero en tu segunda condición. Como el token `||` ejecuta la siguiente instrucción si la anterior "da falso", entonces, pongas lo que sea, se ejecutará lo que está dentro del bucle `while`. Puesto que si no es "s" a la primera, entonces "devuelve verdadero" y se ejecuta, pero si es "s" entonces da falso en la primera y cierto en la segunda, entonces también se ejecuta.

Lo que podrías hacer es cambiar el operador `||` por el de `&&` y tu programa quedaría algo así.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 echo "A continuació s'escriuràn numeros aleatoris."
 echo "Si en qualsevol moment vols parar, pressiona la tecla 's' o 'S'."

 read exit_key

 while  [ "$exit_key" != 's' ] && [ "$exit_key" != 'S' ]
 do
     echo "$RANDOM"
 done
```

Ahora que si, como entendí, quieres hacer que te arroje y te pregunte si desea continuar aventando números uno por uno, puedes usar este script.`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "A continuació s'escriuràn numeros aleatoris."

while :  # Es lo equivalente a un "while True"
do
    echo -n "Si en qualsevol moment vols parar, pressiona la tecla 's' o 'S': "
    read exit_key

    [[ "$exit_key" =~ ^(s|S)$ ]] && exit
    #               ^^^^^^ ------- Usa una expresion regular para asegurarse
    #                              que "exit_key" sea igual a "s" o "S"

    echo "$RANDOM"
done
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.
Me temo que el problema radicaba en el <code>read</code>, que me sobraba el $.
También erraba en el operador del while, no era un OR, era un AND (cosa que no le encuentro sentido, ya que, mientras $exit_key se diferente de 's' o 'S', haz lo que sea).

De todas formas, ya me está funcionando y dejo mi código aquí abajo (no ha sido necesario usar tu expresión regular).

Una vez más, mil gracias.

Comment: @alex-iglesias Si lees mi respuesta, verás que es justamente lo que puse y expliqué el por qué, que tu problema era tanto el `read`  como el `||`.

Comment: Por cierto, no sé cómo escribir como código en una respuesta a una pregunta.
Tengo entendido que con el <code></code>, pero no sé cómo aplicarlo.